# Samba becomes laggy after a few hours of use, requires frequent deamon restarts

Tags: samba, performance

I have a Linux file server with about 40 file shares and 50 clients.  The clients are not usually all connected at the same time, the active number of clients at any given time would be about 50%-75% of the total clients.

The file sharing becomes laggy after a few hours.  If I run a test using [LAN speed test lite](https://old.totusoft.com/lanspeed1.html), I can the test transfer hanging up.

The server is a well-spec'd system: i5-4590, 16GB, Gb ethernet, 2x 500GB Samsung Evo SSDs in a RAID 1 configuration.  The load average is near zero whenever I see it lagging.

Most of the shares are located on a Linux LVM filesystem on the SSDs, a few shares are on an external backup NTFS HDD.

Restarting the samba service seems to resolve for a little while, but it needs to be done every few hours.  I can schedule that to run as a cron job, but I would like to know, why this is happening?

I have a few other servers on ancient Core 2 systems with similar setups and are stable for months without issues like this.

Comment: *a few shares are on an external backup NTFS HDD.* honestly, your NTFS driver is the very most likely culprit here. NTFS doesn't fully do POSIX semantics, and it's possible that samba and that don't play together well. Also, I've lost data to bugs in older NTFS drivers for linux more than once, so a backup disk using NTFS sounds like an extremely bad idea. Simply don't.

Comment: but you would also want to rule out hardware issues. Read what `dmesg` says between starting samba and it hanging. Look for statistics on dropped network packets, TCP retransmissions. Are you seeing a packet loss > 0.5% in a local network? fishy. Mistrust your network card, especially if USB-connected.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I'm aware that NTFS access is relatively inefficient on on Linux, but it's only used infrequently.  I can run a backup targeting the external drive at full throttle (writes > 500mbps), the load average peaks at ~1.75 then quickly falls back to 0.00 once the backup is done.  Also, on the older Core 2 systems, which have over a dozen NTFS volumes each, it's never a problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: `dmesg` shows nothing for samba. Nothing about dropped packets. NIC is onboard. 

This system was previously Win10 and was working well. Linux was installed to handle more connections (Win10 Pro limits to 20 client connections)

Comment: onboard is sadly not a great guarantee. What model of network controller does `lspci` report? There's a few intel integrated NIC that have strange driver bugs...

Comment: and dmesg, being the kernel log, usually shows nothing about services, but things about hardware events etc. Dropped packets however would need to be checked through sysfs, usually

Comment: @MarcusMüller: NIC is Intel I217LM

Comment: it seems that model has problems with 100Mb/1Gb autonegotiation, but other than that should be fine on 1 Gb/s ethernet. Can you check with `ifconfig` how many `RX errors`, `dropped` you have, compared to overall `RX packets` ? (Same for TX would make sense, but I feel it's unlikely that TX is a problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: `RX packets 192130888` `RX errors 0  dropped 5984` `TX packets 405442031` `TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

Comment: On one hand, nah, 31 out of a million packets getting lost is close enough to nothing. then again, the number of dropped packets is strangely pretty darn close to 1 packet all 2¹⁵ packets – let's assume, for the sake of everyone's sanity, that this is just statistics and not something that really drops every 2¹⁵th packet. We can then call this good news, it's not the network :)

Comment: So, sorry to be so nervous about that: there's *nothing* new in `dmesg` when transfers start hanging, right? Smartctl also doesn't see anything wrong with your storage? Next thing you'd do if there's really nothing wrong with hardware is start debugging what the individual threads of samba are doing when hanging – are they blocked reading from some empty file, are they sleeping until something times out… But that kind of debugging means you attach a debugger to your samba process, and learn how samba works internally from source code … not a Friday afternoon thing

Comment: @MarcusMüller: smartctl shows no reallocated sectors for any drives.  I'll look at `dmesg` the next time I see it hang.